# How to get all headers in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I need to receive array of headers in http get request but I see only part of them.

How can I get all headers which I see in response?

The service for getting http request

```
getUserRevenuePerPage(numberOfBils) {
return this._http.get(environment.apiUrl + environment.apiOldSubPath + this._expertRevenueUrl +
  '?perPage=' + numberOfBils);
```

}

The method for receiving array of headers from response

```
getUserRevenuePerPage() {
return this._revenueService.getUserRevenuePerPage(this.numberOfBills).subscribe((data) => {
  this.header = data.headers.toJSON()
});
```

}

Headers which I see:
[image: Headers which I see]

Headers which I receive:
[image: Headers which I receive]

Comment: just use that this.header = data.headers or to access by name use something like this var customHeader = data.headers.get('Custom-header');